# Maximum for Fourier transform results in an error

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

assume for a function $\varphi \in L^1$, that $\varphi \geq 0$ and $\int_\mathbb{R}\varphi(x) dx = 1$. Then the following should hold:

$$|\hat{\varphi}(\omega)| \leq \int_\mathbb{R} |\varphi(x)||e^{-ix\omega}|dx =\int_\mathbb{R}\varphi(x) dx = 1 = \hat{\varphi}(0) 
$$ 
which means, that $\hat{\varphi}$ has a maximum at $\omega =0$.

Therefore 
$$
|0|=|\hat{\varphi}'(0)| = |\int_\mathbb{R}x\varphi(x) dx |
$$
Now assume $\varphi(x)= \begin{cases}1 &  x \in [0,1],\\
0 & otherwise
\end{cases}$ which means all assumptions are fullfiled.

But now $|\hat{\varphi}'(0)| = \frac{1}{2}$

Where is my error?

Thanks for any help
Matthias

Comment: You're forgetting that $\hat \phi$ is complex valued.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is $|\hat\varphi$| that attains its maximum at $\omega=0$, not $\hat\varphi$. In fact, since $\varphi$ is complex valued, it does not make sense to talk about its maximum.
$$
\varphi(\omega)=\frac{1-e^{-i\omega}}{i\,\omega}
$$
and
$$
|\varphi(\omega)|^2=\frac{2(1-\cos\omega)}{\omega^2}=1-\frac{\omega^2}{12}+\dots
$$